# Cannot install Printer MFC-J680DW on Win10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer, network-printer, brother-printer

All of the sudden, maybe after the last windows upgrades, I fail to install my Brother MFC-J680DW all-in-one printer machine.

My windows version is Win 10 Home 10.0.19043 Build 19043.
The driver on Brother's site is from 2017.
Of course I installed it but it does not work for me.

Please ask me for any helpfull information.

Thanks

Comment: I have this ***same exact printer/scanner*** and I am using the drivers from the Brother site on 19042.xxx .. god I hope they don't break my printer...  The [Microsoft catalog drivers](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Brother%20j680dw) are at least a year older but might work where the other ones didn't as John points out below.

Comment: I find the Microsoft Catalogue the be very fine overall and I use it in numerous circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 should have the driver for this printer in the Microsoft Driver Catalogue.

Uninstall the driver and any driver associated apps like scanner - everything to do with the printer.

Now restart the computer. Make sure the printer is connected to the computer.

Open Control Panel, Devices and Printers, click on Add Printer and let Windows install the printer.

More than 9 times out of 10 this will work.